# How Get error messages of antlr parsing?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I wrote a grammar with antlr 4.4 like this :

```
grammar CSV;

file
  :  row+ EOF
  ;

row
  :  value (Comma value)* (LineBreak | EOF)
  ;

value
  :  SimpleValueA
  |  QuotedValue
  ;

Comma
  :  ','
  ;

LineBreak
  :  '\r'? '\n'
  |  '\r'
  ;

SimpleValue
  :  ~(',' | '\r' | '\n' | '"')+
  ;

QuotedValue
  :  '"' ('""' | ~'"')* '"'
  ;
```

then I use antlr 4.4 for generating parser & lexer,
this process is successful

after generate classes I wrote some java code for using grammar

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String source =  "\"a\",\"b\",\"c";
        CSVLexer lex = new CSVLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(source));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        tokens.fill();
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(tokens);
        CSVParser.FileContext file = parser.file();
    }
}
```

all of above code is a parser for CSV strings
for example :  ""a","b",c"

**Window Output :**

```
line 1:8 token recognition error at: '"c'
line 1:10 missing {SimpleValue, QuotedValue} at '<EOF>'
```

I want to know How I can get this errors from a method (getErrors() or ...) in code-behind not as result of output window

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using ANTLR for CSV parsing is a nuclear option IMHO, but since you're at it...

- Implement the interface `ANTLRErrorListener`. You may extend `BaseErrorListener` for that. Collect the errors and append them to a list.
- Call `parser.removeErrorListeners()` to remove the default listeners
- Call `parser.addErrorListener(yourListenerInstance)` to add your own listener
- Parse your input

Now, for the lexer, you may either do the same thing `removeErrorListeners`/`addErrorListener`, or add the following rule at the end:

```
UNKNOWN_CHAR : . ;
```

With this rule, the lexer will never fail (it will generate `UNKNOWN_CHAR` tokens when it can't do anything else) and all errors will be generated by the parser (because it won't know what to do with these `UNKNOWN_CHAR` tokens). I recommend this approach.