# ANTLRErrorListener to get error msg

Tags: java, antlr4

I am trying to get the error msg from ANTLR but I am confused

I replaced the standard ErrorListener like in this [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832429/how-get-error-messages-of-antlr-parsing)

```
public String runAntlr(String sqlFile){
    ANTLRErrorListener error = new BaseErrorListener();

    ANTLRInputStream input;

    try {
        input = new ANTLRFileStream(sqlFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    }

    tsqlLexer lexer = new tsqlLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    tsqlParser parser = new tsqlParser(tokens);

    parser.removeErrorListeners();
    lexer.removeErrorListeners();
    parser.addErrorListener(error);
    lexer.addErrorListener(error);

    ParseTree tree = parser.tsql_file();
    new MyTsqlVisitor().visit(tree);

    System.out.println(error);
    return "Analysis successful";
}
```

This was the text in my console after running:

```
run:
line 2:16 mismatched input 'as' expecting '.'
line 2:19 no viable alternative at input 'date'
line 5:38 mismatched input 'where' expecting {EXCEPT, INTERSECT, UNION, ')'}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

After adding the `ANTLRErrorListener`

```
run:
org.antlr.v4.runtime.BaseErrorListener@4507ed
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Did I implement the `ANTLRErrorListener` right?

Comment: `error.toString()` doesn't work too

Comment: Did you implement it at all? error is just an instance of BaseErrorListener which is generated by antlr with empty methods if I recall correctly?

Comment: I implemented the interface `ANTLRErrorListener`, removed `ErrorListener` from `parser` and `lexer` and add the new one

Comment: Could you please then paste the code of the class BaseErrrorListener which you have implemented? Otherwise hard to say what is wrong...

Comment: I didn't implement `BaseErrorListener`, it is a Class from [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BaseErrorListener.html)

Comment: You wrote in the code "ANTLRErrorListener error = new BaseErrorListener();" and you are using that variable at parser and lexer. Do you know what this does? Where are you using the class you implemented?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103684/discussion-between-nappy-boy-and-cantsleepnow).

Comment: I'm done here. Please learn basic java stuff (like what is an interface etc) then post questions.

Comment: After a short research I implemented now my own ErrorListener and edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working now, here is my solution:

First my implementation of MyAntlrErrorListener:

```
public static MyAntlrErrorListener INSTANCE = new MyAntlrErrorListener();

//When the value is false, the syntaxError method returns without displaying errors.
private static final boolean REPORT_SYNTAX_ERRORS = true;

private String errorMsg = "";

@Override
public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, 
                        Object offendingSymbol, 
                        int line, 
                        int charPositionInLine, 
                        String msg, 
                        RecognitionException re) {

    if (!REPORT_SYNTAX_ERRORS) {
        return;
    }

    String sourceName = recognizer.getInputStream().getSourceName();
    if (!sourceName.isEmpty()) {
        sourceName = String.format("%s:%d:%d: ", sourceName, line, charPositionInLine);
    }

    System.err.println(sourceName+"line "+line+":"+charPositionInLine+" "+msg);
    errorMsg = errorMsg + "\n" + sourceName+"line "+line+":"+charPositionInLine+" "+msg;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return errorMsg;
}
```

and I get the errorMsg in my Main class like this:

```
...
lexer.removeErrorListeners();
lexer.addErrorListener(MyAntlrErrorListener.INSTANCE);
parser.removeErrorListeners();
parser.addErrorListener(MyAntlrErrorListener.INSTANCE);

...

return MyAntlrErrorListener.INSTANCE.toString();
```