# Unable to catch ANTLR4 Syntax errors

Tags: java, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to catch syntax errors in ANTLR4 before I visit the `ParseTree`. Simplified, my grammar for declaring a double is like this:

**Grammar for double type (parser rule):**

```
declare_double: DOUBLE_TYPE  WHITESPACE ID WHITESPACE(EQUALS WHITESPACE DOUBLE)? SEMICOLON;
```

**Grammar for double type (lexer rule):**

```
DOUBLE: [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+ | '.' [0-9]+ | [0-9]+;
```

**Compiler class:**

```java
public class Compiler implements ANTLRErrorListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //CharStream chars = CharStreams.fromString("double a = 3.1415;");
        CharStream chars = CharStreams.fromString("double a = 3;");


        SimpleJavaLexer lexer = new SimpleJavaLexer(chars);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        SimpleJavaParser parser = new SimpleJavaParser(tokens);

        ANTLRErrorListener errorListener = new BaseErrorListener();

        //parser.removeErrorListeners();

        parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);

        SimpleJavaParser.ProgramContext programTree = parser.program();


        TypeChecker visitor = new TypeChecker();
        visitor.visit(programTree);
    }

    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object o, int i, int i1, String s, RecognitionException e) {
        System.out.println("Syntax Error");
    }

    @Override
    public void reportAmbiguity(Parser parser, DFA dfa, int i, int i1, boolean b, BitSet bitSet, ATNConfigSet atnConfigSet) {
        System.out.println("Report ambiguity");
    }

    @Override
    public void reportAttemptingFullContext(Parser parser, DFA dfa, int i, int i1, BitSet bitSet, ATNConfigSet atnConfigSet) {
        System.out.println("Report attempting full context");
    }

    @Override
    public void reportContextSensitivity(Parser parser, DFA dfa, int i, int i1, int i2, ATNConfigSet atnConfigSet) {
        System.out.println("Report context sensitivity");
    }
}
```

If I run this and I do not remove the default listener from the parser, I get the following result:

**Default error listener output**

```
    line 1:11 mismatched input '3' expecting DOUBLE
    line 1:12 extraneous input ';' expecting {<EOF>, WHITESPACE, '(', INTEGER,BOOLEAN, DOUBLE, STRING, ID}
```

The problem that I have is that after this error is displayed, the visitor is instantiated and it will visit the `TypeChecker`. Whenever a error is found, I don't want to continue. I thought that by implementing an error listener like the way I did, I could create my own error messages and stop running the program. I expected the `syntaxError` method to be triggered but it does not. I have used [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832429/how-get-error-messages-of-antlr-parsing) for reference.

How do I appropriately listen for errors and manage them accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Compiler` class implements `ANTLRErrorListener`, but you never use it or even instantiate it, so it doesn't have any effect.

Instead you instantiate `BaseErrorListener`, which does nothing (in fact, I'm a bit surprised that the code even compiled - I would have expected `BaseErrorListener` to be an abstract class).

If you replace `new BaseErrorListener()` with `new Compiler()`, your `syntaxError` method will be called.

PS: I would recommend that you rename your class to something including the words `ErrorListener` because the name `Compiler` certainly does not make it obvious that it's an error listener.

Comment: You were right, I can now accordingly treat errors. Thanks!